# Exception when implementing oauth2 client credentials flow with Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to implement client_credentials flow with spring security oauth2 with spring boot.

But when i'm trying to access a resource method with a token i'm getting this exception.

```
ERROR [org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter] (default task-3) Forwarding to error page from request [/error] due to exception [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.forType(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter;]: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.forType(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter;
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>auth-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

       <!-- Spring Security dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Java EE dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>auth-server</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Here are my spring security configuration files.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception{
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("123456")
                .secret("123456789")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials")
                .scopes("read","write")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600);
    }


}

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/api/users/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')")
                .antMatchers("/").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");
    }


}
```

Here is my rest controller.

@RestController
public class UserController  {

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/users/greeting", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String greeting(){
    return "Hello Greetings";
}

@RequestMapping("/")
public String helloWorld(){
    return "Hello World";
}
```

}

What am i dong wrong here. My initial guess was that there is a conflict of dependencies in jackson. So i added a inclusion in the oauth2 dependency.

But seems its not going to fix the issue. i'm still getting the error.

Can someone help me to resolve this issue.

Best Regards,

Comment: Add the pom.xml or gradle dependencies

Comment: @javaguy updated the question with the full pom.xml file.